# To show clock using form elements

Tags: javascript

I want to show clock using form element like `HH MM SS` but it is not working.
How can I do that?

```html
<html>   
<body>
  <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

    function myTimer() {
      var d = new Date();
      var t = d.getHours();
      var y=d.getMinutes();
      var z=d.getSeconds();
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t+":"+y+":"+z;
    } 
  </script>

  <script>
    function fun1() {
      var d = new Date();
      var t = d.getHours();
      var y=d.getMinutes();
      var z=d.getSeconds();  
      window.document.my.hh.value=t+;
      window.document.my.mm.value=+y+;
      window.document.my.ss.value=+z;
    }
  </script>

  <form name="my">
    HH
    <input type="text" name="hh">
    MM
    <input type="text" name="mm">
    SS
    <input type="text" name="ss">


  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected output like 
A script on this page starts this clock:

```
13:10:24

HH 13 MM 10 SS 24
```

but the actual output is
A script on this page starts this clock:

```
13:10:24

HH  MM  SS
```

Comment: Just Remove that + from t+, +y+, z+, It will work

Comment: Why do you remove the accepting my answer :)

Comment: By mistake. .....................n there's a little change in my question.can u help me out?

Comment: @Honey Can you show the little change of your question?

Comment: @Ryan Nghiem I removed the input type="button' from form element and onclick function

Comment: @Honey So you want value of three inputs change real-time follow the time of element  `<p id="demo"></p>` ?

Comment: @Ryan Nghiem yea, is it possible!

Comment: @Honey Hi guy, I updated my answer. Can u see it

Comment: @Ryan Neighm Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code there:

```
window.document.my.hh.value=t;
window.document.my.mm.value=y;
window.document.my.ss.value=z;
```

This is a demo that I fixed: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/PrQvGq

**Updated:**

The question has a little change.

Then I add `fun1();` into  `myTimer() function`

I updated demo link

Answer (score 0):

Put ID for each input tag, query each of them, and lastly fill the data you want. 
For example:

```
<input type="text" name="hh" id="myH">
<script> 
document.getElementById('myH').value('99999')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could quite easily achieve your target by doing this: (btw it's good practice to store a reference to your elements because getting elements from the DOM can be quite expensive)

```
let clockHolder = document.getElementsByName("my")[0];
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    clockHolder.children[0].value = toDoubleDigits(d.getHours());
    clockHolder.children[1].value = toDoubleDigits(d.getMinutes());
    clockHolder.children[2].value = toDoubleDigits(d.getSeconds());
}

function toDoubleDigits(int) {
    if (int > 9) return int;
    return "0" + int;
}
```

The toDoubleDigits function makes sure you always have 03:07:20 instead of 3:7:20.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```html
<html>   
<body>

  <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <form name="my">
      HH
      <input type="text" name="hh">
      MM
      <input type="text" name="mm">
      SS
      <input type="text" name="ss">

      <input type="button" value="calc" onclick="fun1()">
  </form>
  <script>
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

    function myTimer() {
       var d = new Date();
       var t = d.getHours();
       var y=d.getMinutes();
       var z=d.getSeconds();
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t+":"+y+":"+z;
    }


    function fun1()
      {
        var d = new Date();
        var t = d.getHours();
        var y=d.getMinutes();
        var z=d.getSeconds();  
        window.document.my.hh.value=+t;
        window.document.my.mm.value=+y;
        window.document.my.ss.value=+z;
    }
    fun1()
  </script>
</body>
 </html>
```